# How can I create a VAN for EDI Data interchange?

Tags: edi

Is there a way we can create a new VAN for EDI Data interchange, my Trading partner supports VAN and not direct communication like sFTP.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to be interoperable with all other VANs. Sometimes you just have that one trading partner that doesn't support direct connections because their VAN is also their translator, and there's a contract there.  Your best bet is to find a cheap VAN and get an interconnect to your partner's VAN, or get the business heads talking to each other for FTP/AS2/etc.  If you're the customer, you might get somewhere.  If you're the supplier, the customer is always right.

Comment: Thanks @andrew , do you know a cheap VAN? or any idea how to find one?

Comment: you have to shop around, but there are dozens.  Digital Movers, Kleinschmidt, Liaison (nuBridges), etc.